# What's a cross-browser way to check if a JavaScript variable is a <form> DOM object?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
```

`(form.isDOMForm())` would evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean this:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
alert(form.nodeName);
```

More Info:

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics

Note that you can also use `tagName` but `nodeName` [seems to be a better choice](http://aleembawany.com/2009/02/11/tagname-vs-nodename/).

Comment: @Pekka, not *always*, it could be either upper or lowercase. Please read: http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/ Other than that gotcha, yes, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I think that for HTML it is `form.nodeName == "FORM"` in all browsers. EDIT: what @Aistina said.

Comment: I would also convert it to (e.g.) uppercase before comparing, because I remember observing "FORM" string in firebug - probably case may vary

Comment: `nodeName` and `tagName` are precisely as good as each other in this situation where we know for certain that we're dealing with an element.